SysInternals Process Explorer starts but is unresponsive for a long time, spinning blue disk. Then works fine
I recently downloaded the SysInternals tools. I'm running them on Windows Server 2019. The problem I am having only seems to apply to Process Explorer. I have this problem whether I run procexp.exe or procexp64.exe, same for both. I have also tried running as Administrator vs. not. Again, the problem persists, but other SysInternals tools (e.g. Procmon) seem to work fine and do not display this behaviour.
The problem is that when Process Explorer starts up, the window appears quickly, but then it is immediately unresponsive, and my cursor for that window is the blue spinning ring. I cannot scroll the window or interact with any control, nor can I minimise the window. I can use other windows/applications fine.
After some time (a few minutes, maybe 5), the window becomes responsive and I can use the program as normal.
Is there a way I can prevent this from happening?

I find recent versions of some SysInternals tools to be buggy.  I think the quality of SysInternals tools has decreased noticeably in recent years.

Sounds like a conflict with software running on your system and this particular piece of software

The most likely cause is the particular anti-malware suite on the server delaying startup. You can confirm that by disconnecting the server from LAN and WAN, stopping the real-time antivirus, and then starting Process Explorer. Of course, restart malware protection afterwards. Yes, this is a nuisance, and might only be worth the effort to test if the server were to be taken offline for another reason.

process explorer has been getting slower to load in recent years. a lot of it is just that in modern windows, real time process viewing is more strenuous job than it used to be, though I can't say I've ever seen it take longer than a minute to load.

Thanks everyone for your advice. I did try disabling the windows real time antivirus, but it didn't help.
Does anyone know a trustworthy place where I could try downloading an older version of ProcExp or the Sysinternals suite? I tried searching but I'm not sure if the locations I found were trustworthy.

@BenjaminSelby, regrettably, Microsoft does not make archives available. You could find older versions online, but check at https://www.virustotal.com/#/home/upload for malware.

Thank you @DrMoishePippik

same issue. I can see the CPU at the bottom left get updated but I can't scroll the ProcessExplorer nor interact with it at all. PE version 17.06, on Win 2019 Azure VM.
